# Visual Studio Community 2015 setup failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, visual-studio-community

I have installed VS 2015 recently (windows 10), but there were some package failures (detailed later).

When trying to start a new project, I got an error message: "Compiler could not be created". So i uninstalled, repaired the microsoft redistributiables and tried again.
Since then I can't install VS at all.

I get the following message:

> Roslyn Language Services - x86 : Fatal error during installation.
>
> Visual C++ IDE Debugger Package : Package failed.
>
> Microsoft VisualStudio JavaScript Project System : Package failed.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Diagnostic Tools - x86 : Package failed.
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Diagnostic Tools - ENU : Package failed.

I have already tried to:

- repair using the VS setup
- uninstall, including redistributiables, and re-install
- clear %temp%
- install from offline installer
- apply windows troubleshooter (fixed bad components)
- apply WU
- delete msvcp140.dll (as some forum suggested)

Nothing worked, and I would be very grateful for any help.
Thanks

Comment: To find the detail error message, you need to use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: does your issue is solved or not? If not, would you mind sharing the installation logs?

Comment: Not solved yet, I didn't have access to my desktop since your comment. Would upload later today. Thank you!

Comment: Installation logs: [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvEAsid0ON8EbN7mZZ5qy9aIy1A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following error message from your shared log file “dd_vs_community_20161027000333.log”:

> > Error 0x80070003: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{DE064F60-6522-3310-9665-B5E3E78B3638}v14.0.23107\packages\communitycore\Setup\cab8.cab

Error code “0x80070003” means the specified path couldn’t be found, you need to confirm the existing of the specified folder and try to manually move it.

> > ExecuteError: Package (VC_IDE_Debugger) failed: Error Message Id: 1316 ErrorMessage: The specified account already exists.

I found there have another 3 packages (PerfTools_CORE_x86.msi, PerfTools_RES_enu.msi, vs_RoslynLanguageServices.msi) also have this same issue, you can have a try with the following:

1. Run the [Fixit tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) to automatically repair issues including corrupted registry keys that block you from installing or removing programs.
2. If method 1 not works, take a look at [this similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47af290d-03d2-424e-b459-0d2ea8fb09a0/microsoft-web-deploy-35-package-failed-during-visual-studio-2013-ultimate-installation?forum=vssetup) and directly use the above 4 package files (VC_IDE.Debugger.msi, PerfTools_CORE_x86.msi, PerfTools_RES_enu.msi, vs_RoslynLanguageServices.msi) from a healthy  ISO file of VS community 2015 with update 3 to uninstall then reinstall that components. After that, you can use the ISO file to repair again.

Answer (score 0):

The case is iso image is corrupt.
Login as admin
Make the iso a drive
Start vs community.exe

If preparation .exe error
Just walk to the location. Run it as administrator. Come back to installer and say skip. It will be ok.
For some skip option won't come. So download is only option. Keep the backup of missed ones. So that next installation is foolproof.
The download is in temp folder search by the package name and take backup.
Thanks