# Visual Studio 2015 Community Setup Failed on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have windows 8 and trying to install Visual Studio Community 2015

Visual studio installation setup shows error:

[image]

> ```
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: Setting string variable
> > 'BundleResult' to value '1603' [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i319:
> > Applied rollback package: vs_teamExplorerCore, result: 0x0, restart:
> > None [1560:06BC][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > vs_teamExplorerCore, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{791295AE-3B0A-3222-9E69-26C8C106E8D1}v14.0.23102\
> > [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e000: Error 0x80070642: UX aborted on
> > download progress. [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e000: Error
> > 0x80070642: UX aborted on cache progress.
> > [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed while
> > reading from internet and writing to:
> > C:\Users\STEREO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3}\cabF4FF0EBB32667C881220A7599326BBF7
> > [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to
> > download URL:
> > http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=559005&clcid=0x409
> > [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt
> > to download URL:
> > 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=559005&clcid=0x409' to:
> > 'C:\Users\STEREO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3}\cabF4FF0EBB32667C881220A7599326BBF7'
> > [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return
> > Code=-2147023294 (0x80070642), Error Message=, Result Detail=,
> > Vital=False, Package Action=Download_WinInet, Package
> > Id=aspnetwebfxtoolsvs14 [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e000: Error
> > 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from:
> > 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=559005&clcid=0x409' to working
> > path:
> > 'C:\Users\STEREO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3}\cabF4FF0EBB32667C881220A7599326BBF7'
> > [04DC:0194][2018-09-09T16:07:54]e313: Failed to acquire payload:
> > cabF4FF0EBB32667C881220A7599326BBF7 to working path:
> > C:\Users\STEREO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3}\cabF4FF0EBB32667C881220A7599326BBF7,
> > error: 0x80070642. [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing
> > cached package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu, from path:
> > C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{02138196-59F1-3672-9FB9-BF868075952E}v14.0.23102\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > vs_teamExplorerCore, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{791295AE-3B0A-3222-9E69-26C8C106E8D1}v14.0.23102\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]w353: Unable to remove cached package:
> > vs_teamExplorerCore, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{791295AE-3B0A-3222-9E69-26C8C106E8D1}v14.0.23102\, reason:
> > 0x80070003. Continuing... [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351:
> > Removing cached package: Office365ApiTools, from path:
> > C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{D1E9367F-5F7C-4019-96B7-45967FD60DB4}v1.0.0.0\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > StorageConnectedServices_VS, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{C6A4A3DF-5A1E-4825-8D38-E5B00C196B31}v14.0.23107\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > MobileServicesConnectedServices_VS, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{A4495E4F-5218-48FB-8AD2-F3076011B9E1}v14.0.23107\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > AuthenticationConnectedServices_VS, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{3FEAC561-1CF6-41D6-B0F3-BECDD9C88A1B}v14.0.23107\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > ConnectedServices_VS, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{1B87EE82-EB1D-442C-90A3-D86B08E9B7A1}v14.0.23107\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > nugetvs, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\{2FB312D3-E28F-3094-B6ED-47000F25D193}v3.0.60624.657\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > vs_preclean_vs, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\74CD539E-75F7-3FA3-88CB-B52950873799\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > VSSetupUtility_Start_vs_community, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\14EAB521-B093-30C5-A486-C08CC4309C82\
> > [1560:029C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i351: Removing cached package:
> > Preparation_Uninstall_vs_community, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> > Cache\C9C924BB-4D69-36BB-95C7-87B41A4006CC\
> > [1560:06BC][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i372: Session end, registration key:
> > SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3},
> > resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
> > [1560:06BC][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i371: Updating session, registration
> > key:
> > SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{4f075c79-8ee3-4c85-9408-828736d1f7f3},
> > resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space
> > Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive:
> > 280915968  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 9170944
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after
> > install:  SystemDrive C:\ 79585542144 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 79585542144
> > bytes [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Format Message Failed: 317
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Format Message Failed: 317
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting
> > Parameters [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P1 -
> > vs_community [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P2 -
> > 14.0.23107.178 [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.23107 [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P5 - vs_teamExplorerCore
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P8 - There is a problem
> > with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the
> > setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or
> > package vendor.   [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
> > [04DC:142C][2018-09-09T16:07:54]i399: Apply complete, result:
> > 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
> ```

Tried with the below solution links,
[Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Setup failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688483/visual-studio-2015-enterprise-setup-failed)

[Visual Studio Community 2015 setup failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231594/visual-studio-community-2015-setup-failed)

[image]

PC is also updated

Comment: Would you please share us the detailed log files like Heath's suggestion? Any update?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant bits of the log are missing. The installation already occurred by the time your top line appears (1603 is `ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE`). I recommend running https://aka.ms/vscollect and attaching %TEMP%\vslogs.zip when it completes to a new issue on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/61/index.html. This is for .NET, so please mention to redirect to Visual Studio. Unfortunate at this time, you cannot open new bugs in the Visual Studio tab via the website.